# Sending HTML through JSON using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I'm working with Mercado Livre API.

Since the user is allowed to use HTML in description field, I must allow it too. I'm using AJAX to communicate with Mercado Livre, but when I'm trying to parse a big HTML code, I'm not able to use json_decode on PHP.

How can I encode the user's HTML before sending it to PHP and decode it when it's received?

Comment: Please create a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You first, require encode all HTML and next send this to API, for this, you can use the next function:

```
var encodedHtml = originalHtml.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(idx) {
  return '&#'+idx.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
```

This code is on side client. To decode HTML in your server side, you need the use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php) PHP sentence.

I hope this help you.

Greetings